# What does it mean if the "close" vote number drops?

Tags: support, closing

I noticed on one of my questions there were 3 close votes before (a week or so before), and today when I looked at it the number had changed to 1. What does this mean?

Comment: "Reset"? Does the website use the word "reset" anywhere or could it be something else like close votes expiring?

Comment: @badp Possibly. The close vote number was at 3 about a week or two ago, and when I looked at it today it was only at 1. So I figured that the number had been reset by someone or something.

Comment: I reworded the question to help prevent confusion.

Comment: which question are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close votes expire after a while. I think [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/13992) is the current canonical source on how exactly that works:

> Close votes (and probably reopen votes) only expire after all of these conditions are met:
>
> - 4 days have passed since the last close vote.
> - The question has more than 100 views.

Comment: Don't forget that three "Leave Open/Closed" votes also starts the decay.